# Saving a file from a chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome packaged app that has taken me a while to get my head around but I finally have it working. However I have now come across another problem.

Is it possible to save a variable from my app into a text file that's placed in my app/file directory?

I have looked over the chrome.fileSystem api but I don't really understand it.

I could be completely wrong and maybe you can't save files to the file directory?

Any examples or tutorials on this would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean presenting a save dialog to the user, or modifying files inside your app’s container?

Comment: I believe a save dialog would be great. But my app has a CSS file that I want to overwrite. My app has a CSS editor built in but I would like the user to be able to save their changes to the CSS file.

Comment: This CSS file needs to be accessible outside of the app. Is this possible?

Comment: So, you would need to: read a default content at the first run; allow the user to edit and save changes; allow the user to read the saved file outside of the application. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing the file's contents in chrome.storage and then dynamically loading and saving the contents of your css file from there instead of using the filesystem. To me, this would be much easier to accomplish.

Comment: Would this allow me to access the CSS file after the app is closed?

Comment: what data an app/extension saves to chrome.storage can only be accessed by this app/extension alone.

Answer (score 1):

chrome.storage sounds like a good fit all right (though not too sure about your specific needs in accessing the css outside the app). It's main use case is for saving state and storing configuration settings/variables.

We've a code lab that walks through all kinds of chrome apps stuff, including chrome.storage here: http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_codelab5_data.html

There's also the new syncFileSystem API, which really doesn't seem to fit your needs. This is document/file level synchronization, like getting access to user's files on hard drive, saving them in app, and syncing them.

But sure, if you are curious, here's the docs on working with Chrome File System and sync File System: http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_storage.html

We're also working on a doc that explains the key concepts around storing data in the cloud (specifically for packaged apps). Hoping to have an early cut in trunk over the next week or so.

Keep us posted on how you get on!