# Save a file to filesystem with chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a variable full of css attributes that I would like to use to create a CSS file and save it to the apps file directory. How would I go about this in a chrome packaged app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not going to like this answer. You can't do this, and if you figured out a way to do it, it would be considered a security hole that the Chrome team would close.

Part of the design goals of packaged apps is to make the entire application statically analyzable at the time it's uploaded to the web store. This means that when a user is making the decision whether to install the app from the store, that decision is based on what the code actually does (it contains these scripts, this CSS, and these images, and it asks for these permissions) rather than on whether you trust the developer or the website. www.example.com might look trustworthy today, but tomorrow it might be sold to a new owner, or compromised. So the decision "do I trust example.com?" is hard. Packaged apps make that decision easier; in most cases, the "thing" you're trusting is right there, right in front of you, in the CRX you just downloaded.

If you understand this design goal, then you understand why the design of packaged apps doesn't allow for self-modifying code (which is the generic term for what you want to do). If your code could generate code, then it becomes significantly harder for static analysis to determine what the app could do (either intentionally or through bugs). Along the same lines, Content Security Policy is fairly strict for packaged apps and can't be set to a less restrictive policy, which is why eval() won't work in script.

Is there a reason why your JavaScript can't set your DOM elements' style properties? That ought to give you the flexibility you want without running up against the boundaries of the platform's security model.

Edit: just saw [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070936/saving-a-file-from-a-chrome-packaged-app), which seems very similar to this one. Are you building a CSS editor? Or are you trying to modify your own app's CSS? My answer above assumed the second case. If I've misunderstood your question, then clarify and I'll attempt to improve the answer.

Comment: Really great information. Definately looking at the wrong way of building my app. I am building a CSS editor but it needs to be local. I don't really want to learn a new language and want it to be a standalone app that is based on the desktop. Any advice would be great on next steps. I have been looking at node-webkit that enables me to file to the filesystem whilst using a webkit browser.

Comment: Actually node-webkit is really great! I would suggest anyone looking to do something similar to look at this. Documentation is not great but to be honest it doesn't need to be as most of the work is done with pure node. After playing with it for an hour I was able to write over my existing CSS file and load it back in.

Comment: I understand. Sounds like fun. If you come back to Chrome packaged apps, there are three different APIs for writing files: the HTML5 filesystem API, chrome.fileSystem, and chrome.syncFileSystem. In a nutshell, chrome.fileSystem is good for reading/writing individual files picked by the user. chrome.syncFileSystem removes the user-gesture requirement and adds cloud syncing, but if you want real files that the user can then take and use elsewhere, you'll need chrome.fileSystem to export them from the sync filesystem. Have fun with node-webkit!

Comment: @sowbug is it possible for an app to enumerate files under a static folder? static folder = a folder where static assets such as images are stored. imagine i am writing a book. i write new chapters and save them in a folder, then my app should be able to pick them up automatically without any code changes.

Answer (score 3):

While @sowbug's answer was *technically* correct in that you cannot modify your apps *packaged* content, the OP can still achieve what is essentially the same.

Save css:

```
var someCSSCode = 'a { color:#de0 }';
webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile('my.css', {create:true}, function(file) {
        file.createWriter(function(writer) {
            this.onwriteend = function() {
                this.onwriteend = null;
                this.truncate(this.position); //in case a longer file was already here
            };
            writer.write(new Blob([someCSSCode], {type:'text/plain'}));
        });
    });
});
```

Load css:

```
webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile('my.css', {}, function(file) {
        var elem = document.createElement('link');
        elem.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        elem.type = 'text/css';
        elem.href = file.toURL();
        document.head.appendChild(elem); //or document.body
    });
});
```

Note that this code doesn't include any error handling.