# Printing to parallel port connected printer from chrome apps?

Tags: printing, google-chrome-app, parallel-port

I'd like to create a [chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) that could print to an old POS printer connected to the computer's parallel port. I have seen that chrome apps support USB printing and also can control the serial port. Is it possible to control the parallel port? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As today, there's no API to send data through the parallel port. Is there a way for you to go through a USB-parallel port adapter?

Comment: The parallel port is usually made available by the operating system as a file. see my updated answer. If you can write to a file on your local system you usually also can write to the parallel port.

Comment: Since Chrome Apps environment is sandbox, accessing the files directly won't work.

Comment: I find your suggestion using a USB-parallel port adapter a good idea. I misread your answer last time but SO won't let me change the vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the parallel port like a file and write to it.
How exactly depends on the OS you are using.
I have done this at least in Windows.

It might not work using this API
[Save a file to filesystem with chrome packaged app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076648/save-a-file-to-filesystem-with-chrome-packaged-app)

Using NativeClient should support local file access to files like the parallel port
https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/overview

use `LPT0` as filename on Windows
use `/dev/lp0` as filename on Linux
(where 0 is the number of the parallel port)

On Windows, when the printer is not connected to your local machine you can share the parallel port on the machine where the printer is connected and open a file frome some other windows machine with a file name like `\\othermachine\printersharename`
I guess there is something similar on other OS but I don't know about it.

If you want the printer to make more fancy things than just print text you can write any printer command sequence (all just strings) to the opened 'file' and make the printer do anything it is able to.

Comment: Because the question has no information about the programming language or Operating System to use and because there are probably enough Q/A that show how to access files.

Comment: It does. There is a link to chrome apps in the post above. Here it ts again in text: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html. Also the tags indicate that it is a google-chrome-app related question. It should work anywhere where chrome runs. It uses mainly javascript.